# python list element wise conditional increment

Tags: python, list, increment

I have been searching this for a while, basically I am trying to conditionally increment a list of element by another list, element-wise...

my code is following, but is there a better way to do it? list comprehension, map??

I think a element-wise operator like ~+= from http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0225/ would be really good, but why is it deferred?

```
for i in range(1,len(s)):
        if s[i]<s[0]:
            s[i]+=p[i]
```

based on some good feedbacks from you guys I have recoded to the following

```
i=s<s[0]
s[i]+=p[i]
```

and s,p are both arrays.

p.s still slow than matlab 5 times for one of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a new array, then your options are:

1. What you proposed (though you might want to use xrange depending on the python version)
2. Use Numpy arrays for s and p. Then you can do something like `s[s<s[0]] += p[s<s[0]]` if s and p are the same length.
3. Use Cython to speed up what you've proposed.

Comment: hi,justin, just tried numpy, works well, code can be written as i=s<s[0]
s[i]+=p[i]

Comment: @jerry, yes, you can do that (and should if s is very big).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick version:

```
# sample data
s = [10, 5, 20]
p = [2,2,2]

# As a one-liner.  (You could factor out the lambda)
s = map(lambda (si, pi): si + pi if si < s[0] else si, zip(s,p))

# s is now [10, 7, 20]
```

This assumes that `len(s) <= len(p)`

*Hope this helps. Let me know*. **Good luck. :-)**

Comment: @jerry Did I answer you question?

Comment: @jerry Pure Python will never be as fast as Matlab. Mainly because of the dynamic OO typing.  If you need speed, you will need a python module that is designed for arrays.  Have a look at: http://numpy.scipy.org/

Comment: @jerry If I answered your question, please mark as "answered" and let me know.  Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check this SO question:

- [Merging/adding lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263457/merging-adding-lists-in-python)

Basically, something like:

```
[sum(a) for a in zip(*[s, p]) if a[0] < 0]
```

Example:

```
>>> [sum(a) for a in zip(*[[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]) if a[0] > 2]
[33]
```

To clarify, here's what zip does:

```
>>> zip(*[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

It concatenates two (or more) lists into a list of tuples. You can test for conditions on the elements of each of the tuples.

Comment: i know zip, but the problem is generating a new list waste the old list's memory.

Comment: also for the condition not true, you get a smaller list and lose the element relative position.

Comment: @jerry You are correct on both points, I misread the line where you did the addition. Given that, I don't think there's a better solution than what you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [s[i]+p[i]*(s[i]<s[0]) for i in range(1,len(s))]
```