# Merging lists based on elementwise condition

Tags: python, list-comprehension

## Problem 1

I have four lists of equal length: `A_old, A_new, B_old, B_new` and want to have the following behaviour: If `A_new[i] > A_old[i]` then set `B_old[i] = B_new[i]`.

Tried a straightforward loop implementation:

```
for i, (a_new, a_old) in enumerate(izip(A_new, A_old)):
    if a_new > a_old:
        B_old[i] = B_new[i]
```

And an implementation using a map (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210938/python-list-element-wise-conditional-increment)):

```
B_old = map(lambda (a_new, a_old, b_new, b_old): b_new if a_new > a_old else b_old,
            izip(A_new, A_old, B_new, B_old))
```

But none of these approaches are sufficiently fast. Note that I cannot use `numpy` arrays and boolean arrays because the elements of `B_new, B_old` are not numeric.

To put things on a more formal footing, a sample implementation is provided here: https://gist.github.com/1986588 and the runtimes are as shown below:

```
Naive: 1.13343191147
Mapping: 1.45240283012
kev: 1.09499907494
Numpy: 0.0525879859924
Where: 0.0651860237122
```

## Problem 2

Having evaluated different options `numpy` slicing with boolean arrays seems to be the way to go. However, I have now encountered a new problem:

Let `B_new` be not an array but simply a value `val`. Then the best variant reads

```
B_old[A_new > A_old] = val
```

This works fine as long as `val` is not iterable but fails when it is. In particular, `val` is a tuple here. I would like to assign the tuple `val` to the elements of `B_old` where `A_new > A_old`.

A workaround seems to be to let

```
val2 = np.empty(1, dtype=object)
val2[0]=val
B_old[A_new > A_old] = val
```

but this seems convoluted. The problem is that I do not know what the type of val is. It might be iterable and it might not.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for the performance? What do you mean by "not sufficiently fast"?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer: The algorithm I am working on computes many convolutions which are rather expensive. However, the above consumes ~50% of the computational resources. On the other hand, a simple `np.maximum(A_new, A_old)` consumes hardly any resources but is of the same basic form as the above problem.

Comment: FWIW, you can use `numpy` arrays for non-numeric objects.  But I'm not sure this would speed up anything here.

Comment: Have you considered writing a C extension for that? You shouldn't be able to get a lot faster than the straightforward `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was having trouble when creating a numpy array and subsequently adding elements of a different type. E.g. the following fails `a=np.empty(10); a.fill('test')` with the following error message `ValueError: could not convert string to float: test`. Having tried it for numerical values it gives bad results.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, had a think about that but it seems like a bit of a hassle. Do you know of good tutorials to get into writing C extensions?

Comment: @TillHoffmann: Using a tool like [Cython](http://cython.org/) for this job should not take too much effort. It also has [documentation](http://docs.cython.org/).

Comment: You should also look into the `numpy.where()` function -- something like `numpy.where(A_new > A_old, B_old, B_new)` (or maybe with `B_old` and `B_new` swapped).

Comment: Yes, added `where` to the list of options. 
@wim: Ran into another problem detailed above.

Comment: That's because `np.empty` will default the dtype to float.  You have to specify a different dtype.

Comment: Is the workaround above the easiest way to achieve that behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

```
B_old = [B_new[i] if A_new[i]>A_old[i] else B_old[i] for i in range(len(A_old))]
```

Comment: The above suggestion is unfortunately slower than the two implementations I already tried.