# Adding values in a nested list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging/adding lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263457/merging-adding-lists-in-python)

```
nested_list= [[1, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
sum_of_items_in_nested_list = [4, 7, 10]
```

I am trying to create a nested for loop that will add take the item at each corresponding index and add it to the other nested list at the same index.  So the above adds
`nested_list[0][0] + nested_list[1][0]`, `nested_list[0][1] + nested_list[1][1]` and so on.  I would like to do this without importing and modules.  This is probably so easy but I am having the devil of a time with it.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 4):

use `zip()`:

```
In [44]: nested_list= [[1, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5]]

In [45]: [sum(x) for x in zip(*nested_list)]
Out[45]: [4, 7, 10]
```

another way, using nested loops:

```
In [6]: nested_list= [[1, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5]]

In [7]: minn=min(map(len,nested_list))   #fetch the length of shorted list

In [8]: [sum(x[i] for x in nested_list) for i in range(minn)]
Out[8]: [4, 7, 10]
```

Comment: How would you do this with using a nested for loop?  I am trying to understand how to do this and I am just not "getting it"

Comment: @user1761521 nested for loop is not required for this.

Comment: @user1761521 I've added another approach for doing this with nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

you may also think about this solution:

```
map(int.__add__,*nested_list)
```

Better style:

```
from operator import add
map(add,*nested_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for your case , and you can use `len()` to change the lengths of your lists.

```
nested_list= [[1, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5]]

sum_of_items_in_nested_list=[]
for j in range(0,3,1):
    result=0
    for i in range(0,2,1):
         result=result+nested_list[i][j]
         sum_of_items_in_nested_list = sum_of_items_in_nested_list + [result]
```