# How to add the sum of lists in a program? (python)

Tags: python, list, sum

For example,

```
a = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
```

sum returned should = 45

Comment: Related answer you will get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263457/merging-adding-lists-in-python

Answer (score 4):

Use [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sum) in a nested fashion:

```
>>> a = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
>>> sum(sum(x) for x in a)
45
>>> # This also works
>>> sum(map(sum, a))
45
>>>
```

If you want them, here is a reference on [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) and one on [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Answer (score 3):

Here's another answer that hasn't yet been proposed:

```
from itertools import chain
a = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
sum(chain(*a))
```

This uses `sum` with [itertools.chain()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until
>   it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the
>   iterables are exhausted. Used for treating consecutive sequences as a
>   single sequence. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def chain(*iterables):
>     # chain('ABC', 'DEF') --> A B C D E F
>     for it in iterables:
>         for element in it:
>             yield element
> ```

By passing `*a` to chain, `a` is expanded so that its members become the arguments to chain

```
sum(chain([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])
```

And we end up with a flattened list (well, iterable actually), equivalent to

```
sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Can you explain the chain function? Seems good..

Comment: Ya I get it.. Nice function..

Answer (score 1):

Use the sum function

```
s = 0
for i in a:
    s += sum(i)

print s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
total = 0

for i in a:
  total += sum(i)
```

This assumes that the list only contains lists that are full of numbers. If you want to be smarter than that, you'll need to make a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
print reduce (lambda x, y: x + y, map(sum,a))
```

`map(sum, a)` gives: `[6, 15, 24]`
`lambda x,y: x + y` is a function which adds the inputs `x`, `y` 
`reduce` sums the entries together to get 45.

Additionally, `sum(map(sum,a))` will also work, based on the same premise, with simpler syntax, but `reduce` and `lambda` are good things to know nonetheless.

Comment: I like the use of reduce, but not such a fan of map. How about `reduce(lambda total,next: total+sum(next), a, 0)`

Comment: @PeterGibson Seems unnecessarily convoluted.  What's wrong with `map`?  I'm a fan, and it's good to get used to the `map-reduce` paradigm.

Comment: `map` on python builds a new `list` which can be slow and a bit of a memory hog. Still I agree it is simpler.

Comment: Actually, looks like this is no longer the case in Python 3, so I retract my suggestion :)

Comment: @PeterGibson Yeah, they changed `map`, probably for the better.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
sum(sum(a, []))
```

The inner `sum` flattens the list by adding the sublists to the empty list - equivalent to

```
sum([] + [1,2,3] + [4,5,6] + [7,8,9])
```