# How to increment values in a list in python without using the for loop?

Tags: python, list

in Python how to increment the values in a list without having to write a `for` loop, e.g.:

```
group  = [0]*3
item   = [1,2,3]
group += item
print group
```

to get `group = [1,2,3]` instead of `group = [0,0,0,1,2,3]` ?

Comment: Why increment? Why not copy the item into group?

Comment: Something like this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/263457/1558022

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050824/add-sum-of-values-of-two-lists-into-new-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do element-wise operations (addition in this case) by using `zip` within a list comprehension.

```
>>> group = [0]*3
>>> item   = [1,2,3]
>>> group = [i + j for i,j in zip(group, item)]
>>> group
[1, 2, 3]
```

This is a general solution if `group` didn't start out as all zeroes, and you wanted to add the current values with some new values.

Answer (score 2):

You could use numpy module. This won't  need a `for` loop.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> group  = np.array([0]*3)
>>> item   = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> group += item
>>> group
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> list(group)
[1, 2, 3]
```